# How do stream video from my site and play in unity app?

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, server, video-streaming

I want to make a archive of my videos (high quality videos) on my site or other sites and I want to stream them online from the **unity** exported app. 
How can I make stream option because if I preload it in the app, the size of the app is very big which is not needed, want the app to be small in size. 
I also tried using YouTube streaming in the app but it only support up to 720p using plugin available on the asset store. Any steps or tutorials is much appreciated. Can someone please help I am stuck here and do not know how to do this.

Comment: Easy Movie Texture is a plugin to play videos on Android/IOS and have the streaming option, is not free btw

Comment: @cjf93 do you know how to use the streaming option

Comment: you need to put the url in the MediaPlayerCtrl it's explained in the plugin manual

Comment: @cjf93 Thanks for the help

Comment: I added as answer, if you solved it using the plugin mark as correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a Android/IOS app you can use a plugin called Easy Movie Texture, is not free but the plugin works great and the support is very good too.

All you need to do is add the MediaPlayerCs.cs to the gameObject who will be the "screen" then assign the path of your video in the inspector.(in your case an url)

All of this is explained in the plugin manual.
Link to plugin: https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/10032

Comment: is there a way to download videos through the same asset in the app itself?

Comment: i think that you should use the WWW class from unity https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WWW.html to download data from url

Comment: actually I want the video to download and play after in the app itself.. how can it be done using the asset. I asked the support but didn't got anything helpful